# Django REST framework no CSRF token with runserver but with runserver_plus

Tags: django-rest-framework, csrf, django-extensions

Using django-extensions' "runserver_plus" command, I've no problem with CSRF token. The token is defined in cookies as expected in server responses after login and I use it to sent it back to server in HTTP headers during unsafe HTTP requests (POST, PUT, etc...)
But for some reasons, I have to not use "runserver_plus" anymore and switch back to legacy "runserver" command. And since, the CSRF token I get from server after login does not work anymore. I got the error `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`. There is no other changes in the code. Just switch from runserver_plus to legacy runserver.

I really don't understand why. It's a mistake for me.

Of course, REST framework authentication classe is SessionAuthentication

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Is someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found why. It's because I use a underscore in HTTP header name for setting the CSRFTOKEN : I do this in javascript : `header['X_CSRFTOKEN'] = mytoken`. But because production servers strip underscored header name runserver do so. runserver_plus does not have the same behavior and allow underscored http header names.
Replacing my javascript by `header['X-CSRFTOKEN'] = mytoken` (dash instead of underscore) make it work.